# Incomplete packages for kinetic armhf jessie

Tags: ros, armhf, ros-kinetic, jessie

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wanted to install ROS kinetic on by beaglebone black.
The image I have installed is a debian jessie, which is the recommended image to handle all of the beaglebone black features.
And I just saw that currently almost nothing is compiled for kinetic jessie armhf, while all packages are available for the kinetic ubuntu xenial armhf.
I used to have the ubuntu xenial on my beaglebone and ros was nicely working, unfortunately to have the easiest access to internal feature of the beaglebones (PRUs), the debian jessie is the image best maintained, so I switched to this image. but now I am kind of stuck as almost no package are available for this version.

is this a temporary limitation, and I just need to wait that packages are compiled and provided for my combination, or is this kind of a mid-long term limitation and I should look into another solution for my setup ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239466/incomplete-packages-for-kinetic-armhf-jessie/) by [Bobox](https://answers.ros.org/users/27011/bobox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-07-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-14**:
Could you give some examples of packages you are missing? Base Debian Jessie (amd64) builds include [about 700 pkgs](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_dj.html) for kinetic. For (I guess) ARMv8, it's also around [700](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_djv8.html).

**Comment by [Bobox](https://answers.ros.org/users/27011/bobox/) on 2016-07-14**:
All of the ros-kinetic- packages are missing.
I can see some python-ros..  , rosbash
On servers :
http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages      is 51Ko
http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-arm64/Packages     is 687Ko
and xenial amhf is 609ko

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-14**:
That's certainly strange. Perhaps @tfoote can shed some light on this. I'm not an ARM expert, so I might be misinterpreting the status pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are not building packages for Kinetic Jessie Armhf. We are only building amd64 and arm64 for Jessie. The few packages you see are architecture independent and are available to support the source build toolchain.

If you would like to run Kinetic on armhf we recommend using an Ubuntu Xenial base for which we are building armhf packages.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rouno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4024/rouno/) on 2016-07-19**:
Hi, is there any release scheduled yet for Kinetic Armhf + Ubuntu 16.04 ?

**Comment by [Bobox](https://answers.ros.org/users/27011/bobox/) on 2016-07-19**:
Kinetic for armhf on ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) is already available.
Just followbthe standard kinetic ubuntu installation. Packages are there.

**Comment by [Rouno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4024/rouno/) on 2016-07-19**:
My bad, I wanted to refer to Arm64 instead